# Jenkins cucumber reports to show on main job's page

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I run cucumber tests as part of a continuous integration for one of my products. I use the [Jenkins cucumber-reports](http://www.masterthought.net/section/cucumber-reporting) plug-in.
It all works well and is very useful!

I'd like to be able to show the reports on the main Jenkins job's page and not under an inner page in the job.

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) plugin? I have been using it for monthes and I used it to customize my jenkin's **Homepage**. It give you the ability to add any portlet into your jenkins **Homepage**. This is how my jenkins **Homepage** looks like after I started to use this Dashboard View plugin. I am not sure if it support cucumber report or not but at least you can have a try.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it does not support cucumber reports. Also, I want the report in the main job's page. Not in the main Jenkins page/view.